# Force MS Access parameters to pop up in specific order

Tags: ms-access, parameters, ms-access-2010

I have a query in an MS Access `.accdb` database. I have multiple parameters as criteria for columns in the query.

I would like the parameter popup windows to be displayed in a different order than is the MS Access default.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just re-order the columns in your query (drag them, or choose the order when designing).

Alernatively you can view the query in SQL mode and re-order them there.